# Need to use Mod_Rewrite in Wordpress 3.4.1 But It's Not Working - I've tried as much as I can think of

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks

On any other site this is a piece of cake...however with Wordpress, I cannot for the life of me get this to work. I have tried everything and anything I can think of and or even research. I absolutely 100% need to get this working properly.
**Example: page-language.php?lang=english is rewritten with /language-learning-software/learn-how-to-speak-english to make it SEO friendly**

my .htaccess is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^language-learning-software/learn-how-to-speak-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /wp-content/themes/bizway/page-language.php?lang=$1 [N]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have hostgator, if that helps at all. I have sppoken with support for over an hour and nothing came from it except they cannot change "AllowOverride" to "All" - I feel this might solve it but I guess it's not possible since it's a "shared" host.

Is there any plugins that can pull this off? Any way to customize permalinks? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.